# Broken CSS on all pages except Homepage & if via Customize.php

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

> procureure.com/types-de-droits

Here's how it looks via customize.php
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY2ey.jpg)

I was not doing any major changes. Cleared cache and changed stuff in customize.php but thats it.

I've been working for 2 straight days to get a decent gtmetrix score and overall design. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tell us how are we suppose to check what is wrong?. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Just a quick note: GTmetrix score/ Pingdom or google page speed test
>   are just recommended approach and the speed they show does not
>   necessarily mean real world differences. Those scores do not cover the
>   complexity of code of the server side (which also delays the page load
>   time). So there are scenarios where you have to ignore few of the
>   recommendations to make sure everything works fine.

Although in your case i can see that there are no css on you page applied externally nor internally. Kindly tweak the css rendering settings to see if it works. The theme is working fine on customize.php because the changes do not affect the back end of the website it's only the front end which gets affected. So CSS are rendering on back end but not of the frontend. It maybe of theme issue if css are not enqueued properly. there can be serveral reasons. Switch to one of the default themes and see if the plugin is working properly. This will help you find out where exactly the problem exists.

Comment: Managed to get frontend css working when adding a revslider to the page for some reason. Patched and works now.